# Jmeter: parameterization issue with request Body

Tags: jmeter

I am sending the following request with one parameterization parameter ${id} and request looks like
 **Actual Message:**

```
{"Data":"{\"Source\":\"#include <stdio.h>\\nint main()\\n{\\nint n;\\nprintf(\\\"Enter an integer\\\");\\nscanf(\\\"%d\\\", &n);\\nif (n%2 == 0)\\nprintf(\\\"Even\\\");\\nelse\\nprintf(\\\"Odd\\\");\\nreturn 0;\\n}\",\"Lang\":\"c\",\"callback_url\":\"callback_url_string\",\"cid\":\"159:60719:2667:${id}\"}","Action":"compile","TenantId":"159","UserId":"0","CID":"159:60719:2667:${id}","LanguageId":"25331"}
```

But while sending the request JMETER is altering the request (removing the few formats like \'s) and sends to the server and server responds with bad request response.

**JMETER Sends like:**

```
{"Data":"{\"Source\":\"#include <stdio.h>\nint main()\n{\nint n;\nprintf(\\"Enter an integer\\");\nscanf(\\"%d\\", &n);\nif (n%2 == 0)\nprintf(\\"Even\\");\nelse\nprintf(\\"Odd\\");\nreturn 0;\n}\",\"Lang\":\"c\",\"callback_url\":\"callback_url_string\",\"cid\":\"159:60719:2667:558019\"}","Action":"compile","TenantId":"159","UserId":"0","CID":"159:60719:2667:558019","LanguageId":"25331"}
```

**IF you send above request without parameterization (enter values) then it works fine.**

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a POST HTTP request and the body section has this data

could you please point the HTTP body to  below relative path starts from bin directory

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(path/to/payloadfile.txt,,)})}
```

Now payloadfile.txt can have the actual content still it will evaluate ${ID} and further variables as well.

if that helps dont forget to click answered. Happy to help, Happy Testing

REFINE:

I have used online tools :

first to see the data in the fisrt place is a proper one https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I see this

```
{  
   "Data":{  
      "Source":"#include <stdio.h\/>\r\n int main()\r\n {\r\n int n;\r\n printf(\"Enter an integer\");\r\n scanf(\"%d\", &n);\r\n if (n%2 == 0)\r\n printf(\"Even\");\r\n else\r\n printf(\"Odd\");\r\n return 0;\r\n "
   },
   "Lang":"c",
   "callback_url":"callback_url_string",
   "cid":"159:60719:2667:${id}",
   "Action":"compile",
   "TenantId":"159",
   "UserId":"0",
   "CID":"159:60719:2667:${id}",
   "LanguageId":"25331"
}
```

I separated out C program alone

```
#include <stdio.h/>
 int main()
 {
 int n;
 printf("Enter an integer");
 scanf("%d", &n);
 if (n%2 == 0)
 printf("Even");
 else
 printf("Odd");
 return 0;
 }
```

and applied escape characters using online tool [applied java script escape]

http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html#ad-output

output:

```
#include <stdio.h\/>\r\n int main()\r\n {\r\n int n;\r\n printf(\"Enter an integer\");\r\n scanf(\"%d\", &n);\r\n if (n%2 == 0)\r\n printf(\"Even\");\r\n else\r\n printf(\"Odd\");\r\n return 0;\r\n }
```

this the one i used and it shown valid json document. if you are not sending valid json document server will throw error. do not select encoding in HTTP sampler

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your suggestion but still request is going wrong as mentioned above. One thing I observed that is \n and printf/scanf... are causing this issue.

Comment: if you are sending it from a file ,Why cant you parameterrise the c program in to a file and refer that file , with this you dont have to put \n and escape characters   then in your c program, now payload part looks "Source":"${${__FileToString(path/to/cprogram.txt,,)}} "

Comment: Actually I am recording the some script and try to run again, while recording it records properly but after adding  parameterization parameter ${id} and try to run again then I am facing the above Issue.

Comment: please attache the screenshot of the request went through jmeter . I mean view results tree screenshot for this particular request . you can do that by editing your question and attach pic. By the way where is this ${id} coming from did you store that in to a variable named id before using it

Comment: This is the recorded value by the JMETER:

{"Data":"{\"Source\":\"# Python Program to Reverse a Number using While loop\\n \\nNumber = int(input(\\\"Please Enter any Number: \\\"))\\nReverse = 0\\nwhile(Number > 0):\\n    Reminder = Number %10\\n    Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder\\n    Number = Number\\nprint(\\\"\\\\n Reverse of entered number is = %d\\\" %Reverse)\",\"Lang\":\"python3\",\"callback_url\":\"callback_url_string\",\"cid\":\"159:60719:2667:1000\"}","Action":"compile","TenantId":"159","UserId":"0","CID":"159:60719:2667:1000","LanguageId":"25336"}

Comment: On my use case, on each iteration I need to send different user id, hence I stored all the user id's in one CSV file and reading the used id's from that file using ${id} and using the same (${id}) on JMETER ansd request looks like as below

Comment: {"Data":"{\"Source\":\"# Python Program to Reverse a Number using While loop\\n \\nNumber = int(input(\\\"Please Enter any Number: \\\"))\\nReverse = 0\\nwhile(Number > 0):\\n    Reminder = Number %10\\n    Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder\\n    Number = Number\\nprint(\\\"\\\\n Reverse of entered number is = %d\\\" %Reverse)\",\"Lang\":\"python3\",\"callback_url\":\"callback_url_string\",\"cid\":\"159:60719:2667:${id}\"}","Action":"compile","TenantId":"159","UserId":"0","CID":"159:60719:2667:${id}","LanguageId":"25336"}

Comment: After running JMETER View Results Tree shows request like:

{"Data":"{\"Source\":\"# Python Program to Reverse a Number using While loop\n \nNumber = int(input(\\"Please Enter any Number: \\"))\nReverse = 0\nwhile(Number > 0):\n    Reminder = Number %10\n    Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder\n    Number = Number\nprint(\\"\\n Reverse of entered number is = %d\\" %Reverse)\",\"Lang\":\"python3\",\"callback_url\":\"callback_url_string\",\"cid\":\"159:60719:2667:555518\"}","Action":"compile","TenantId":"159","UserId":"0","CID":"159:60719:2667:555518","LanguageId":"25336"}

Comment: It's reading the ${id} parameter properly from the CSV file but request was not in a proper format when sent.

Comment: i hope the problem is , the recording provides you already escaped charecters and again you are sending back the escapedOf(escaped()) .. please put the "Source" value in to a file with no escape chareters , only c program i have pasted and refer file using __FileToStringfunction . it helps , another way is just take the program alone apply escaping in online tool and put that value in  "Source":"string you got from escaping in online" , I hope this helps